# Repeated Reporting Services Login issue when deploying through BIDS to a remote server

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

We are having a problem deploying a reporting services report to a sql reporting services computer that is configured in SharePoint Integrated mode. I can successfully deploy to the SharePoint document libraries set up for reports and data connections if I do it locally from the box that SharePoint and Reporting Services are deployed on. If I try and do the same thing with the exact same deployment properties from a remote box, I constantly get a Reporting Services Login dialog popping up and no combination of domain\username and password will work. I've even tried the machines local admin account and still nothing.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Is it the dreaded multi hop issue?

Comment: Try Server Fault - http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen serverfault before. I posted on there yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this issue. Basically the build of sql server 2008 reporting services I installed added an RSWindowsNegotiate setting into rsreportserver.config file and I was running the reporting service under an account other than Network Service. I removed the RSWindowsNegotiate setting and just left the RSWindowsNTLM setting and everything started working properly for us.

More info can be found here, [Solving the Reporting Services Login Issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/lukaszp/archive/2008/03/26/solving-the-reporting-services-login-issue-in-the-february-ctp-of-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when BIDS cannot connect to the Report Server instance. Check the URLs, and see if any firewall is blocking the connectivity to the remote RS instance.

Comment: Thanks Faiz. I tried the url to Report Server and it's getting through fine. The firewall is switched off as well right now, as I thought it might be blocking something.