# deploying reports to report server

Tags: sql-server, iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I configured SSRS 2008 on a remote server.
I can access the report manager from my local machine using `http://SERVER_NAME/Reports_INSTANCE_NAME`

problem is that when I try to deploy a report from BIDS, I get the "reporting services login" dialog box that asks me for user and password. I try my AD user and it doesnt work.

I already added myself to all possible roles, including System Administrator.

I saw online that the problem maybe with the IIS website that must be configured to allow anonymous access. That's fine, but where can I configure that since SSRS2008 doesn't create the websites on IIS anymore (also read that online) and I don't seem to have this possibility using the Reports Service Configuration Manager

Comment: Im running BIDS on my local box and the server is in another computer on the network

Comment: yes, roles in SSRS. ok, which permission should I add and where? I mean, SSRS is running under Network Service and my AD user that Im using to connect is sa on that box...

Comment: If you used the roles in SSRS: `Content Manager`, `Publisher` &c, then you found what you needed. Shouldn't need particular permissions for the machine or SQL server. I just wanted to make sure you got the right "roles."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the link below...it's in reference to 2008 CTP, but there are still some items to check in your setup...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukaszp/archive/2008/03/26/solving-the-reporting-services-login-issue-in-the-february-ctp-of-sql-server-2008.aspx

Similar issue / resolution here as well...
[Repeated Reporting Services Login issue when deploying through BIDS to a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363664/repeated-reporting-services-login-issue-when-deploying-through-bids-to-a-remote)

Answer (score 0):

In your report configuration file, try removing the RSWIndowsNegotiate from the Authentication tag:

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
         <RSWindowsNegotiate />
    </AuthenticationTypes>
   <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```