# Login prompt in deploying report to SharePoint 2013 in integrated mode

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013, integrated

I have sharepoint 2013. I have one SQL instance in sharepoint integrated mode and another instance in SSRS native mode on my server.

I get the login failure error.

[image]

[image]

I am dealing with this failure that is explained in the following solutions. But non of them solved my problem:

I did this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445068/779408

and this:

http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/how-to-fix-%E2%80%9Cnot-able-to-deploy-report-to-sharepoint-2010-in-integrated-mode%E2%80%9D/

then I tested this solution:

http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-ssrs-integrated-mode-deploy-login-prompt#.U5vQj7EmFKb

and implemented the solution in this:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16656/not-able-to-deploy-report-to-sharepoint-2010-in-integrated-mode

Now I have the following web application and its Document library

http://test.local:44444/sites/sc1/Reports

But I can not deploy my reports on it.

What should I do now??

Comment: I am having this same issue, and have gone through all the links in your question, did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This issue normally occurs due to incomplete installation. Ensure that SQL Server Reporting services Add-in for sharepoint is installed. If not, run SQL Server setup again to install the missing add-in. If SharePoint 2013 is missing service pack 1, it may cause errors during configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make use of the release configuration manager. You can create releases such as

```
LOCAL
REPORT_TESTING
REPORT_STAGING
PRODUCTION 
SOME_SHAREPOINT_DEPLOYMENT
```

Each release type contains it's own instance of configuration values. This would allow the release type to control the deployment. If you are not using SharePoint locally then you can set the LOCAL release configuration  to the standard SSRS values on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

this issue happening when you deployment the SSRS reports on SharePoint mode and configure FBA on the SP server

**To solve this issue you must extend the Web Application that include BI Center**

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue,
When creating a new service application in SharePoint using **SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application**, I forgot to check the Web Application to be Associated.
**Solution:**
After I checked the Web Application & updated the service application properties, its Working.
Hope it helps someone...
[image]